# How to get a document to display its contents in quick look

Tags: macos, textmate, quicklook

Is there a way to associate a file type (*.md from Github) in a such a way that its contents are 'visible' with OS X's quick look?

I've associated the extension (*.md) with TextMate, but this doesn't have the desired effect.

Other text files (e.g. *.rb) work with quick look as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install QLMarkdown plugin for Finder:

https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown#installation

> QLMarkdown is a simple QuickLook generator for Markdown files. It
>   renders a preview of the selected Markdown file using Discount

Answer (score 0):

First (like you probably already tried):

- Find, an `*.md` file in finder
- press <kbd>apple</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to
  get info
- change the "open with" to textmate
- press <kbd>Change
  All</kbd>.

If that is not enough, maybe this helps:

> [How to Associate TextMate With CoffeeScript Files](http://igstan.ro/posts/2011-04-21-how-to-associate-textmate-with-coffeescript-files.html)

you would have to do it accordingly to the .coffee files

Comment: The file-association worked, as did the icon assignment.  Unfortunately, quick look still doesn't 'see' its contents.